# Flutter app using pagewise package and JSON

Tags: json, flutter

I am building an APP using pagewise package and would like to get the totalCount var from an external JSON request.

I have a function that returns an INT value that will be the totalCount but when added to the totalCount parameter it returns an error:

```
type 'Future<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int'
```

How can I solve this matter?

UPDATE:

```
return PagewiseGridView(
  pageSize: 6,
  totalCount: getTotals(),
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
  childAspectRatio: 0.555,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  itemBuilder: this._itemBuilder,
  pageFuture: BackendService.getPage,
);
```

this is the class that creates the grid.

Comment: Can you please offer more details on your code? I will try to provide an example on how to retrieve something form a request in the meantime.

Comment: updated with the return of the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't pass a future to a variable that expects an int.

You need to await for the future to complete and while you are awaiting you could, for instance, display a centered circular indicator.

This is something that you could use in your State class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _totalCounter = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getTotalCounter();
  }

  void getTotalCounter() async {
    _totalCounter = await getTotals();
    setState(() {});
  }

  // Simulate your future
  Future<int> getTotals() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 100);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _totalCounter == -1
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : PagewiseGridView(
            pageSize: 6,
            totalCount: _totalCounter,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            childAspectRatio: 0.555,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            itemBuilder: this._itemBuilder,
            pageFuture: BackendService.getPage,
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: getting a error on initState: error: The method 'initState' isn't defined in a superclass of 'StatelessWidget'.

All my classes are StatelessWidgets. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yeah. This is the State class for a `StatefulWidget`. You must have used a `StatelessWidget`. I have added the widget part in front of the _MyHomePageState` code that I had provided at the beginning.

Comment: So... I changed my main.dart to extend the classes just like You proposed and it work a little strange dow... what I mean with strange is that it should stay loading for 3 seconds... but it keeps loading. If I hot reload, then it will work as expected. Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes. You're right. I had forgotten to add the call to `setState()`. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[From the dart documentation:](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures)

A future is a Future object, which represents an asynchronous operation that produces a result of type T.

In your case it is something you need access the info after it was retrieved async.

```
    // Performing a request

// ... some widget 
// ... child/Center is here just to exemplify how to use this Future inside a widget
// child: Center(child:  
    FutureBuilder<CustomList>(
        future: fetchPost(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // USE HERE THE DATA: 
            // snapshot.data.allCustoms        
            // snapshot.data.allCustoms.length 
            // for example you can create a ListView here  
    enter code here
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        })

    // Making a request example (called above) 

    Future<CustomList> fetchPost() async {
      final response = await http
          .get('https://some_api_example');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // was successful, parse 
        return CustomList.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      } else {
        // not successful, throw.
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
      }
    }

    // Some custom object we need to parse 

    class Custom {
      final String id;
      final String info;

      Custom({this.id, this.info});

      factory Custom.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        return Custom(
          id: json['id'].replaceAll(" ", ""),
          info: json['info'].replaceAll(" ", "")
        );
      }
    }

    // A list of custom objects we parse from the reqeust

    class CustomList {
      final List<Custom> allCustoms;

      CustomsList({
        this.allCustoms,
      });

      factory CustomList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
        allCustoms = new List<Custom>();
        allCustoms = parsedJson.map((i) => Custom.fromJson(i)).toList();

        return new CustomList(
          allCustoms: allCustoms,
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: So... I changed my main.dart to extend the classes just like You proposed and it work a little strange dow... what I mean with strange is that it should stay loading for 3 seconds... but it keeps loading. If I hot reload, then it will work as expected. Any Ideas?

Comment: In what method are you calling the FutureBuilder? And what type of object is calling it? (subclass of StatelessWidget and on the build method?)

Comment: Sorry @Andrei Durnea. My answer was to the other solution proposed. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following code and let me know what error are you getting.

```
return FutureBuilder<CustomList>(
    future: fetchPost(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {

        return PagewiseGridView(
          pageSize: 6,
          totalCount: snapshot.data,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
          childAspectRatio: 0.555,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          itemBuilder: this._itemBuilder,
          pageFuture: BackendService.getPage,
        );

      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    })
```

Comment: error: The return type 'int' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure on return snapshot.data and return 0

Comment: Updated the respose